# Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using local maven repo in "D:\maven\repository" .And my all environments are like this:

[image: I'm using local maven repo in "D:\maven\repository" .And my all environments are like this:]

But when I execute "compile" it shows:

[image: Error]

It just means "Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath", I've searched the questions of this kind,but couldn't work :-(

Comment: Don't use references to external images etc. better past the text into the question...some of us have restrictions to access binary files like you used..

Comment: Thank for your advice!

Comment: But you didn't change it...